# extjs: fill red color in holidays

Tags: extjs

I am testing with Extjs demo.

http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/remote.html

I have some holidays: for examples 2011-03-23,  2011-04-11,...
I want to fill red color that holidays

How I can do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
for (i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
 for (k =0; k < rowCount; k++)
 { 
   var record = grid.getStore().getAt(k);  
   var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(i); 
   var val = record.get(fieldName);
   if (isHiliday(val)) 
   {
     var cell = grid.getView().getCell(k, i);
     var el = Ext.get(cell);
     el.addClass('background-red-style');
   }
 }
```

and do not forget to include

```
.background-red-style
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It is not Extjs grid. It is a calendar!

Comment: `addClass` has been [deprecated since 4.1](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-addClass) use `addCls` instead.